# ICollection<T> Vs List<T> in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, list, ef-code-first, ienumerable, icollection

I only watched a few webcasts before I went head first in to designing a few Entity Framework applications. I really didn't read that much documentation and I feel like I am suffering for it now.

I have been using `List<T>` in my classes, and it has worked great.

Now I have read some documentation and it states that I should have been using `ICollection<T>`. I changed to this, and it didn't even cause a model context change. Is this because both `List<T>` and `ICollection<T>` inherit `IEnumerable<T>`, and that is what is actually required for EF?

However, if this is the case, why doesn't the EF documentation state that it requires `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: There is a recent [2015] CodeProject article which explains the difference in much detail and graphical representation with **sample code**. It is not focused directly at EF but still hope it will be of greater help: [List vs IEnumerable vs IQueryable vs ICollection vs IDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Entity Framework would use `ICollection<T>` because it needs to support `Add` operations, which are not part of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Also note that you *were* using `ICollection<T>`, you were merely exposing it as the `List<T>` implementation. `List<T>` brings along with it `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>`.

As for your change, exposing via the interface is a good choice, despite `List<T>` working. The interface defines the contract but not the implementation. The implementation *could* change. In some instances, perhaps the implementation could be a `HashSet<T>`, for example. (This is a mindset you could use for more than just Entity Framework, by the way. A good object-oriented practice is to program towards the interface and not the implementation. Implementations can and will change.)

Comment: So.... just for me to understand a bit further - List inherits IList, which inherits ICollection, which inherits IEnumerable?

Comment: Yes, that's the chain. `List<T>` has to implement each of those interfaces (`IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`) because of the inheritance hierarchy. For completion, `IList<T>` also picks up the non-generic `IList`, `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` interfaces.

Comment: Thank you... Some of the Ixxx features still escape my understanding! You have made sense, however, one last thing that is annoying me, if the other Ixx's inherit IEnumerable, how does it add to the IEnumerable if an Ienumerable is read only? ... If it is too complex, don't worry, when I have a bit of time, I will try to fire up reflector!

Comment: Normal Linq operations do not add or mutate things, they simply filter, group, project, etc. Forward-only, read-only sequences are all that's necessary to support those operations. When you have a Linq provider such as Entity Framework that deals with data persistence, the ability to Add is a substantial benefit that requires a beefier interface, which is what invites `ICollection<T>` to the party (and this interface brings along with it `IEnumerable<T>`, so the "normal" Linq operations are still valid).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I think it's strictly incorrect to say that all three interfaces must be implemented. Since IList<T> inherits ICollection<T> which inherits IEnumerable<T>, it is sufficient for List<T> to simply implement IList<T>.

Comment: @CraigJ, depends on what you mean by implementation. List<T> has to implement each interfaces' methods and properties. List<T> does not have to *declare* it is implementing those interfaces (beyond just IList<T>), as that fact is already transitively declared.

Comment: I am a little late to the party for this convo, but with the inheritance of List<T>, would it take more time for each one? Like would ICollection be faster to define? If that makes sense?

Comment: If you started using ICollection<T>, then EF will put a HashSet<T> there. If you remove an entry from a HashSet and then add a new one, it will go in the place of the deleted entry, while adding an entry to the List<T> after deletion will add it to the end.
This may matter if you are using the database response in views.

Answer (score 86):

They picked the interface they did because it gives a comprehensible abstraction over the magic queries the Entity Framework performs when you use Linq.

Here's the difference between the interfaces:

- `IEnumerable<T>` is read-only
- You can add and remove items to an `ICollection<T>`
- You can do random access (by index) to a `List<T>`

Out of those, `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` map well to database operations, since querying and adding/removing entities are things you might do in a DB.

Random access by index doesn't map as well, since you'd have to have an existing query result to iterate over, or each random access would query the database again.  Also, what would the index map to?  Row number?  There aren't a lot of row number queries you'd want to do, and it isn't useful at all in building up bigger queries.  So they simply don't support it.

`ICollection<T>` is supported, and will allow you to both query and change data, so use that.

The reason `List<T>` works to begin with is because the EF implementation ends up returning one in the end.  But that's at the end of your query chain, not at the beginning.  So making your properties `ICollection<T>` will make it more obvious that the EF creates a bunch of SQL and only returns a `List<T>` at the end, rather than doing queries for each level of Linq that you use.

Answer (score 10):

ICollection differs from IEnumerable in that you can actually add items to the collection, whereas with IEnumerable you can't. So in your POCO classes, for instance, you want to use ICollection if you intend to allow the collection to be added to. Make the ICollection virtual to benefit from lazy loading too.

Comment: I want to understand - you can do the same operations (and more!) with List<T>. Why ICollection<T>? Why not List<T>? Looks simpler and more powerful.

Comment: List<T> Implements ICollection and IEnumerable. More operation but with that comes more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ICollection<T>`, EF will put a `HashSet<T>` there.

This may matter if you are using database models in views.
For example, because the "add" operation  works differently in a `HashSet` and a `List`.
In a `HashSet<T>`, a new element being added will take the place of previously removed elements.
While in `List<T>` new elements are always added to the end.