# ASP.NET MVC3 - ICollection Editor AddRemove Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I know how EditorTemplates work in ASP.NET MVC3. I read a lot and make some research but could not find anything that could help me.

I have a simple model:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<SubModel> SubModels { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to add/remove SubModel when I edit MyModel...

Comment: What do you mean on 'add/remove SubModel'?

Comment: If you look at the `ICollection` interface you will see that it does not have methods to add or remove items, use `IList` instead.

Comment: @DZL the [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface definitely has `Add` and `Remove` methods. It's the [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655845/icollectiont-vs-listt-in-entity-framework) collection type for Entity Framework.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your asking. Could you elaborate? Also have you tried anything yourself? We can't help you with questions like this.

Comment: @HenkMollema Yes, ICollection<T> has Add and Remove, not ICollection

Comment: @DZL ah my bad, you're right. Never seen the non-generic `ICollection` hehe.

Comment: @HenkMollema, to make things simple : Let's say you have an apple tree (MyModel). You edit the tree. On the same page, you can change it's name and add or remove apples (SubModel) from the tree....

Comment: Then why don't you use a generic `ICollection<Apple>` which makes adding and removing items trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [`following blog post`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) in which Steven Sanderson presents a nice approach to handle this. He also used a custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper in order to generate non sequential indexes for the corresponding input fields and enable to dynamically add/remove rows.