# Model Containing a IEnumerable property insert using entityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following 2 models:

```
public class Alert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlertDatetime { get; set; }
    public bool Unread { get; set; }
    public int? ReadByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReadDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool AlertHasRecords { get; set; }

    //Error Reporting and Recording.
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<AlertRecord> Records { get; set; }
}


public class AlertRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HospitalNumber { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }
    public string CrisNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }

    //Link it back to the master Alert!
    public int AlertId { get; set; }
    public virtual Alert Alert { get; set; }
}
```

Once the "Alert" Object properties have values in them, I am trying to use EntityFramework to inset this object into my SQL DB like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static Alert MainAlert = new Alert();
    private static PrimaryDBContext db = new PrimaryDBContext();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAlert = AlertObjectFactory.GetAlertObject();            
        db.Alerts.Add(MainAlert);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The AlertObjectFactory.cs and The Class responsible for building the list of AlertRecords are here(They are large class files)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67a2ae0192257ac51f39

The "Alert" Table is being populated with data, however the 4 records in the
   IEnumerable Records
are not being inserted...

Is this functionality possible with EF?

Comment: I don't see where you're adding 4 `AlertRecords` to your `MainAlert`.

Comment: We need to see your code in the `GetAlertObject()` method. We still don't see where you're populating the data.

Comment: @DStanley I have edited my question to show the method call to my "AlertObjectFactory" the Class responsible for filling the object with its data.

Comment: I have uploaded the 2 class files in question to Gist as they are quite large.

The class generating the data within the Records property is: AlertRecordImporter.GetAlertObjects()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your `IEnumerable` to something that implements `ICollection` such as `List`
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655845/icollectiont-vs-listt-in-entity-framework) answer for more details

Comment: Perfect, Fixed the problem!

Comment: Fixed it for me 7 years later.