# EF Core 3.0 mapping IEnumerable with private List

Tags: ef-core-3.0

Model

```cs
    class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public IEnumerable<TagAttribute> TagAttributes => _tagAttributes.AsReadOnly();
        private List<TagAttribute> tagAttributes;
    }

    class TagAttribute
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set;}
        public int  TagId { get; set; }
    }
```

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) to configure a backing field

```cs
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           

            // This works
            //var t = modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Tag.TagAttributes));
            //t.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);

            // This does not
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
                .Property(q => q.TagAttributes)
                .HasField("tagAttributes")
                .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        }
```

Can anyone explain what the difference is in these methods, please?

This is the error I receive when using the 2nd method to configure the backing field...

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Tag.TagAttributes' is
> of type 'IEnumerable' which is not supported by current
> database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the
> property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
> 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Comment: change `private List<TagAttribute> tagAttributes;` property to  `private ICollection<TagAttribute> tagAttributes;`

Comment: may all ready answered [Model Containing a IEnumerable property insert using entityFramework
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219634/model-containing-a-ienumerable-property-insert-using-entityframework)