# Many-to-many query in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am following this example which I got from http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is how would I construct my query to get posts given TagId?  Something like:

```
public List<Post> GetPostsByTagId(int tagId)
{
    //linq query here
}
```

Please keep in mind this is EF7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first advice is change your collection properties to `ICollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. You can find a really good explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655845/icollectiont-vs-listt-in-entity-framework).

Now going back to your real problem, this is how I would do your query:

```
public List<Post> GetPostsByTadId(int tagId)
{
    using(var context=new MyContext())
    {
      return context.PostTags.Include(p=>p.Post)
                             .Where(pt=> pt.TagId == tagId)
                             .Select(pt=>pt.Post)
                             .ToList();
    }
}
```

You will need to eager load `Post` navigation property because EF7 doesn't support lazy loading, and also, as @Igor recommended in his solution, you should include `PostTags` as a `DbSet` in your context:

```
 public DbSet<PostTags> PostTags { get; set; }
```

**Explanation:**

Your query start in `PostTags` table because is in that table where you can find all the post related with an specific tag. See the `Include` like a inner join with `Post` table. If you apply a join between `PostTags` and `Posts` filtering by `TagId`, you will get the columns that you need. With the `Select` call you are telling you only need the columns from `Post` table.

If you remove the `Include` call, it should still work. With the `Include` you're telling explicitly that you need to do a join, but with the `Select`, the Linq provider of EF is smart enough to see it needs to do implicitly a join to get the `Posts` columns as result.

Comment: Not sure how this works, as I am new to EF, but this query created the most efficient SQL statement: `PostTags INNER JOIN Posts...` where other answers resulted in absolutely horrendous nested SELECTs statement: `SELECT from Posts WHERE (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM PostTags...` Can you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

```
db.Posts.Where(post => post.PostTags.Any(pt => pt.TagId == tagId));
```

Comment: This works and is probably the easiest solution, but looking at the sql profiler, this created a rather complicated and inefficient query with the CASE statement and nested selects.  Not sure why...

Comment: @WheelBuilder Because EF Core still lacks proper LINQ-to-SQL translation and non-straight forrward queries are not translated to SQL and therefore executed in memory on client side performing N smaller simplier SQL queries. For example same happening with GROUP BY that for now to-SQL translation not supported (it performs in-memory making simple SQL query for every entry in the table) and only expected to be implemented in EF Core v1.1 and not in fully.

Comment: Only this solution allowed me to fetch the children objects (Tags) for Posts. But you need to rewrite it with Includes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really specific to EF7.

You could extend your DbContext to include `PostTags`

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PostTags> PostTags { get; set; }
```

Then your query

```
db.Posts.Where(post => db.PostTags.Any(pt => pt.PostId == post.PostId && pt.TagId == tagId))
.Select(post => post);
```

Answer (score 0):

include theinclude both works fine... but only problem is intellisense not identifying or showing the methods just type and then proceed all works fine ...

```
            var res = await _context.Diseases.Include(x => x.Disease2Symptom)
            .ThenInclude(z => z.Symptom).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.