# How do I define an entity class to be shared as a collection across multiple entities using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core with PostGreSQL in an ASP.NET Core Web API. I'm having difficulty defining a set of entities where both Class A and Class B
contain a collection of Class C.

The resulting tables / columns that get generated during a DB migration are not what I'd expect.

Consider the following table definitions:

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public List<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
    public List<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
}

public class Commodity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CommodityId { get; set; }
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }
}
```

These classes result in the following tables / columns being generated:

```
Suppliers
   SupplierId
   SupplierName
   
Consumers
   ConsumerId
   ConsumerName
   
Commodities
   CommodityId
   CommodityName
   ConsumerId
```

How do I create the model class definitions so that the generated tables/columns preserve these relationships? Is there a way to enforce join tables getting created?

Is there a specific set of class/field annotations that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
}

public class Commodity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CommodityId { get; set; }
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }
   
    [Foreignkey("Supplier")
    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    
    
    [Foreignkey("Consumer")
    public Guid ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public Consumer Consumer{ get; set; }
}
```

To understand ICollection and IList better, I'd recommend:
[ICollection vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655845/icollectiont-vs-listt-in-entity-framework)

And this webpage has some good information about different relationships with EF.
[One-to-Many with EF](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)

As per the default convention, EF makes a property as foreign key property when its name matches with the primary key property of a related entity. [DataAnnotations](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: thx for the detailed explanation and links. Didn't know about ICollection<T> vs List<T>

Answer (score 1):

Given that these are one-to-many relationships, we'll want the Commodity table to be pointing to the Supplier and Consumer tables. You should add the relationship columns explicitly in the Commodity model:

```cs
public class Commodity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CommodityId { get; set; }
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }

    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public Guid ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public Consumer Consumer { get; set; }
}
```

No need to change the Supplier and Consumer models. This change should set up `SupplierId` and `ConsumerId` to be foreign keys, and then you should be able to access the relationships from either side.